# Dockerfile: How to put a .jar in the PATH

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I would like to put a `.jar` in the VM PATH (in Linux) but when I run the container, it shows me that the link put in the PATH is not found.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM amancevice/pandas:1.2.1
RUN apt-get update -yq \
&& apt-get install nodejs -yq \
&& apt-get clean -y 
FROM store/oracle/serverjre:1.8.0_241-b07
COPY *.jar /Files/
CMD [ "PATH=$PATH:/Files/json-simple-1.1.jar" ]
```

Comment: Are you running docker build from the directory with the jar files.

Comment: could you add the error log too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMD` you probably want is something like:

```
CMD ["java","-jar","/Files/json-simple-1.1.jar"]
```

If what you really wanted is to run the `jar` - then `PATH` changes are not needed as `java` already is in the `PATH`

---

But, if your `jar` can run directly as an executable (or as a Java script) and that is what you want - run it directly - check that the `*.jar` files you copy over have executable permission in the Docker image.

```
RUN chmod u+x /Files/*.jar
```

Also `PATH` does not allow to add executable files to it directly - `PATH=$PATH:/Files/json-simple-1.1.jar` does not work. `PATH` allows only directories added to it, and searches in those directories for files that are executable.

So:

```
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/Files"
```

Should work and expand the environment variable properly further on. Then, if `jar` is executable - it can be invoked by the literal name `json-simple-1.1.jar` as expected.

Comment: Hi, it seems there is an unwanted trailing backquote in the `RUN` snippet

Comment: Ah, thanks, @ErikMD, happens all the time.
I was a long platform user, and got annoyed that I can not upvote responses. So currently just started contributing to StackOverflow, so just got enough karma to do stuff.

If something - I prefer to just fix typos to one another - it reduces one-two less step/s, if the karma access allows.